# High CPU Usage on postgresql instance

Tags: postgresql, database-performance, amazon-rds

We are using db.m4.large instance. 
Application processes tweets with urls for certain hashtags

The question how to figure our what causes the issue?
Application uses only 1-5 connections. After adding indexes to the most popular queries average cpu usage seems to lowered, but not much(see last several hours on the charts)

[image: pgadmin 4]

[image: rds console]

Comment: Not sure if RDS allows that, but have you checked slow queries? Or even just plain pg_stat_activity to see what kind of queries are running at any given time...

Comment: Maybe your data model is wrong? (CPU is for idiots)

Comment: @jcaron I did. the most popular (I'd say 90%+ of queries) completes within a second according to this query `SELECT  (now() -pg_stat_activity.query_start ) as timee, pg_stat_activity.query FROM pg_stat_activity WHERE state IN ('idle in transaction', 'active');`

Comment: @wildplasser what do you mean by wrong. the part that's actively used is simple. 3 tables, tweet, author -  tweet has one hashtag(we just ignore others) and one author.  We only store tweets with URLs. So in order to find duplicates we search in tweets table by hashtag id and url (we do some normalization, but url is just a string)

Comment: One second is a long time for a query that is used a lot. You do have appropriate indexes? Please share that most frequent query, along with its execution plan (`EXPLAIN`, `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`) and the schema of the relevant tables (including indexes, and if your query does any inserts or updates, the relevant triggers, constraints, etc.).

Comment: `We only store tweets with URLs.` There you go. Tweets_status have a (64 bit) id, which is the PK within twitter. (you could have at least a UNIQUE constraint on it) The URL you mention  is probably functionally dependent on this id. [similar for tweeps]

Comment: How many rows in each table?

Comment: there were millions. But we fixed that by just adding missing indexes:)